# $.ajax POST randomly won't submit data

Tags: jquery, ajax, database, post

I'm working on a site where I'm updating info on D&D characters. On this particular page there is editable divs in which I make changes and submit via (a very inconsistent) ajax POST script.

Somehow the POST won't submit any changes, it could be totally random. Sometimes it works and updates the DB and sometimes it doesn't. Of course it's impossible for you guys to make a POST to my server but the ajax is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#actor_result").load('xml/actortoxml.php?owner=cederman&id=2');
      $('#save_editable').click(function() {
        var name = $(document).find('#actorname').text();
        var current = $(document).find('#currenthealth').text();
        var max = $(document).find('#maxhealth').text();
        var effects = $(document).find('#actoreffects').text();
        var notes = $(document).find('#actornotes').text();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'actor_profile.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                update: 'true',
                actorid: 2,
                actorname: name, currenthealth: current, maxhealth: max, actoreffects: effects, actornotes: notes
            },
        });
        window.location = 'actor_profile.php?id=2'
    });

/*
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $("#actor_result").load('xml/actortoxml.php?owner=cederman&id=2');
   }, 300000);
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
*/
});
</script>​
```

Check the fiddle here for illustration:
http://jsfiddle.net/CgLmW/2/

Comment: Have you tried it without the window.location line?

Comment: Hmm, I tried just now and it seems to fix it, strange =/

Comment: Is it possible for it to autosave?

Answer (score 1):

Since `$.ajax` is asynchronous, you're redirecting away from the page before the ajax request can complete. This redirect causes the ajax request to get killed before it can complete successfully.

Move your redirect statement to a success callback.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'actor_profile.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        update: 'true',
        actorid: 2,
        actorname: name, currenthealth: current, maxhealth: max, actoreffects: effects, actornotes: notes
    },
    success : function() {
        // gets called when ajax request completes successfully
        window.location = 'actor_profile.php?id=2';     
    },
    error : function(err) {
        // in case of error
        console.log(err);
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks that did it, perfect! While I have your attention, how do I add support for less common characters in the input? I'm swedish and would like to use characters as åäö etc (possibly extended to most characters).

Comment: Encoding is a tricky beast (or atleast I think so). You'll need to make sure your database, server etc. are all running the same encoding. I'd recommend creating a  new question with more specefics.